# function pointer not working for int

Tags: c, pointers

Im trying to use the power of function pointers, it all went fine until i tried to make the function pointer use a 2nd argument as type int.

The code below generates an error, which is displayed below
In an header file:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct UnitTag {
    int x;
    int y;
    void (*move)(Unit, int);
} Unit;
```

**Error:**

```
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘int’
     void (*move)(Unit, int);
                        ^
```

void (*move)(Unit); works all fine, which surprises me how adding an argument can cause an error.

I call my struct in a C file, by including header and then doing:
Unit units[UNITCOUNT];
units[0].move(&units[0], 1);

**Update:**

adding:

```
typedef struct UnitTag Unit
```

Causes the error to dissapear, however I can no longer use the function as before.

```
error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘units[i].move’
   units[0].move(&units[0], 0);
   ^
```

note: expected ‘Unit’ but argument is of type ‘struct UnitTag *’

Comment: It should be void (*move)(struct UnitTag, int); I don't know how void (*move)(Unit);  is working for you.

Comment: @MayurK, it gives same error even when using "void (*move)(UnitTag, int);"

Comment: @LamaCoder You missed the `struct` keyword.  `void (*move)(struct UnitTag, int);`

Comment: You need the word struct there.

Comment: @LamaCoder, I updated my comment. It is void (*move)(struct UnitTag, int);

Comment: Remove the &, in this case, notice that you will copy the struct every function call, maybe what you really want is void (\*move)(Unit\*, int)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm getting you, you can simply use `struct` keyword:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct UnitTag {
    int x;
    int y;
    void (*move)(struct UnitTag, int);
} Unit;

void Test (struct UnitTag test1, int test2)
{
    printf("Test1.x: %d\n", test1.x);
    printf("Test1.y: %d\n", test1.y);
    printf("Test2  : %d\n", test2);
}

int main(void)
{
    Unit units[100];

    units[0].move = Test;
    units[0].x    = 1;
    units[0].y    = 2;

    units[0].move(units[0], 3);
}
```

Output:

```
Test1.x: 1
Test1.y: 2
Test2  : 3
```

If you want to pass struct by referebce, simply:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct UnitTag {
    int x;
    int y;
    void (*move)(struct UnitTag*, int);
} Unit;

void Test (struct UnitTag *test1, int test2)
{
    test1->x = 4;
    test1->y = 5;
}

int main(void)
{
    Unit units[100];

    units[0].move = Test;
    units[0].x    = 1;
    units[0].y    = 2;

    units[0].move(&units[0], 3);

    printf("units[0].x: %d\n", units[0].x);
    printf("units[0].y: %d\n", units[0].y);
}
```

Output is:

```
units[0].x: 4
units[0].y: 5
```

Comment: Seems to be working, however will I able to modify the struct, am I passing this by reference that is.

Comment: I replace UnitTag with Unit in the code, and also remove the struct keyword in the argument for Test. And it seems to work fine aswell, just to improve readability, is this however bad practice to do?

Comment: @LamaCoder It isn't a bad practice, as far as you don't hide pointers with typedef.

Answer (score 1):

You need the prototype for Unit before using it.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct UnitTag Unit;

typedef struct UnitTag {
    int x;
    int y;
    void (*move)(Unit, int);
} Unit;

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

After the clarification what you wanted to do. It probably makes more sense to give a pointer to Unit, so that the move command which returns void can change something about your object.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct UnitTag Unit;

typedef struct UnitTag {
    int x;
    int y;
    void (*move)(Unit *, int);
} Unit;

Unit test;

/* some function that corresponds to the interface */
void myMove(Unit *u, int i)
{
    u->x = u->x + i;
}

int main(void)
{
    /* initialize test struct */
    test.x = 0;
    test.y = 0;
    test.move = myMove;

    test.move(&test, 5);

    printf("Values after move are (x, y) = (%i, %i).\n", test.x, test.y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell how void (*move)(Unit);  is working?

Comment: It solved that error, however now I cant use the function the same way as i did before, the error is: 
error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘units[i].move’
   units[i].move(&units[i], cycles);
   ^
note: expected ‘Unit’ but argument is of type ‘struct UnitTag *’

Now I am getting this error everywhere Im using this. The definition of the array is: Unit units[UNITCOUNT];

Comment: You should post the code where you are using the struct.